# Rails 4 + Delayed Job: Handle Return Values from Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a DJ that performs an operation that returns a value. Is it possible to catch the value returned by the performed method?

I've tried something like this:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass < Struct.new(:user_id)
    attr :return_value
    def perform()
      @return_value = OtherModule::OtherClass.the_method
    end

    def success(job)
      puts @return_value.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

But that doesn't work as it shows `nil` when there is a result. Any idea?

Comment: No, it is not possible in the context of anything rather then `perform`, you should use some kind of shared storage for this matter

Comment: Perfect! I will try to do this inside the perform method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveJob's `around_perform` to catch the return value:

```
class VideoProcessJob < ActiveJob::Base
  around_perform do |job, block|
    value = block.call
    puts value # => "Hello World!"
  end

  def perform
    "Hello World!"
  end
end
```

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-around_perform

Not sure if there's a pure-DJ way to do this, but the original question predates ActiveJob so not sure it's important ;)